# Azure Data Factory - Multiple activities in Pipeline execution order

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I have 2 blob files to copy to Azure SQL tables. My pipeline with two activities:

```
{
    "name": "NutrientDataBlobToAzureSqlPipeline",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Copy nutrient data from Azure BLOB to Azure SQL",
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BlobSource"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlSink",
                        "writeBatchSize": 10000,
                        "writeBatchTimeout": "60.00:00:00"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsAzureBlob"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsSQLAzure"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "01:00:00",
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst"
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 15
                },
                "name": "FoodGroupDescriptions",
                "description": "#1 Bulk Import FoodGroupDescriptions"
            },
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BlobSource"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlSink",
                        "writeBatchSize": 10000,
                        "writeBatchTimeout": "60.00:00:00"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "FoodDescriptionsAzureBlob"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "FoodDescriptionsSQLAzure"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "01:00:00",
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst"
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 15
                },
                "name": "FoodDescriptions",
                "description": "#2 Bulk Import FoodDescriptions"
            }
        ],
        "start": "2015-07-14T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2015-07-14T00:00:00Z",
        "isPaused": false,
        "hubName": "gymappdatafactory_hub",
        "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
    }
}
```

As I understand, once first activity is done, second starts. How do you then execute this pipeline, instead of going to Dataset slices and run manually? Also **pipelineMode** how can I set up to OneTime only, instead of Scheduled?

Answer (score 2):

In order to have activities run synchronously (ordered) the output of the first pipeline will need to be an input of the second pipeline.

```
{
"name": "NutrientDataBlobToAzureSqlPipeline",
"properties": {
    "description": "Copy nutrient data from Azure BLOB to Azure SQL",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "BlobSource"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "SqlSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 10000,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "60.00:00:00"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsAzureBlob"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsSQLAzureFirst"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "01:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst"
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 15
            },
            "name": "FoodGroupDescriptions",
            "description": "#1 Bulk Import FoodGroupDescriptions"
        },
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "BlobSource"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "SqlSink",
                    "writeBatchSize": 10000,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "60.00:00:00"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsSQLAzureFirst",
                    "name": "FoodDescriptionsAzureBlob"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "FoodDescriptionsSQLAzureSecond"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "01:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst"
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 15
            },
            "name": "FoodDescriptions",
            "description": "#2 Bulk Import FoodDescriptions"
        }
    ],
    "start": "2015-07-14T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2015-07-14T00:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "gymappdatafactory_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

If you notice the output of the first activity "FoodGroupDescriptionsSQLAzureFirst" becomes an input in the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to execute both the activities without manually executing the dataset slices.

You can do that simply by defining the dataset as external.

As an example

```
{
    "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsAzureBlob",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "linkedServiceName": "AzureBlobStore",
        "typeProperties": {
            "folderPath": "mycontainer/folder",
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat",
                "rowDelimiter": "\n",
                "columnDelimiter": "|"
            }
        },
        "external": true,
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Day",
            "interval": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Observe that the property **external** is marked as true. This will move the data set in a ready state ***automatically***.
Sadly there is no was to mark the pipeline as run once. After running the pipeline once you have an option of setting the **isPaused** property to true to prevent further executions.

**Note:** **external** property can be set to true only for input data sets.
All the activities which have input data set which is marked as ***external will be executed in parallel***.